# How git clone add .git suffix to URL through http(s) server

Tags: git

I setup up a git http(s) server with Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache2(2.4.7). I created a folder name test.git under /home/char/git/. And I successed with

> ***git clone https://test.com/test.git***

but failed with

> ***git clone https://test.com/test***

For git protocal both could work. I tried git update-server-info and many others ways in Git Pro, but still blocked here. Does anyone know the reason why http(s) server failed with leaving out .git. following is my config in apache2

```
        ServerName test.com
        DocumentRoot /home/char/git
        <Directory "/home/char/git">
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Git Repositories"
        Require valid-user
        </LocationMatch>

        SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/char/git
        SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
        SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
        ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/   

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/gitdata/mygit_ssl.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/gitdata/mygit_ssl.key
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because some repos are called `<something>` and that others are called `<something>.git` (especially bare repositories).